# How to connect through Bluetooth with a CMP-10BT mobile printer

Tags: printer, bluetooth

I have [CMP-10BT](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/english/printer/mobile/cmp_10/index.html) mobile printer and I am trying to connect to it through Bluetooth so I can use it but don't how.

Here is what it says in the instructions for the Bluetooth communication:

```
For the Bluetooth communication, it is necessary to choose CMP-10BT and set the DIP switches for Bluetooth.
As built-in Bluetooth module supports Serial Port Profile, host machine needs to communicate with CMP-10BT based on serial port profile. Please refer to the software manual of the host machine for details. When CMP-10BT connects through Bluetooth interface, the host machine may require a pin code. The last 4 characters of the Bluetooth Address that prints on the printer self test are the pin code that should be entered in to the host machine.
```

I don't quite get that - what are those DIP switches?

Here is section from the instructions on the DIP Switch Setting:

Either Bluetooth or IrDA function of CMP-10BT have to be chosen by DIP switches.
DIP switches are located under the battery.
Function allocation of DIP switch is as follows.

- No.1 - No.2
- Bluetooth - ON - ON
- ON - ON
- OFF - ON
- IrDA         - OFF - OFF

There are no "No. 1", "No. 2", "ON" or "OFF" signs on the actual case like the above drawing. Standard CMP-10 does not have Bluetooth function and has no DIP switches.

So I guess there is some kind of switch under the battery but I can't seem to get the battery out and there are some cables possibly attached to it and I am afraid not to break it. What do you recommend doing?

EDIT: I managed to get the battery out and there really are two switches underneath I flipped them both but still no Bluetooth connection!

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual the two dip switches should be in the "ON" position for the BlueTooth to be enabled.

Further down the manual it states that if the presence of the RS-232 cable is connected 9and communicating) then it will default to the RS-232 cable over the BlueTooth/IrDA. **Make sure  your RS-232 cable is not plugged in, to rule this out**.

The instructions state that the BlueTooth communication is done using Serial over BlueTooth so you're going to need to make sur eyou've got the drivers installed for both the printer and your BlueTooth adapter. You'll probably need to conect using the BlueTooth screen, first, to the printer, and then configure the seerial settings through the printer dialogue (Printers and Scanners in Windows) to configure the printer communication...

Comment: I am trying to connect to it through Android but Android doesn't detect at at all the printer, do I need to do something in order of my device to see the mobile printer or is there something wrong with the printer?

Comment: What positions are the DIP switches? Set them both to "ON" and then turn off the device.... turn it back on... see if your Android device can see the printer in the BlueTooth settings.

Comment: I tried them both ways and my device doesn`t detect any Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Turn the printer off (by pulling the cable out). Plug the power cable in. Press and hold the power button for around 5 seconds... the LED should turn red and yous hould hear a buzz. You should then receive the current configuration. It will then print askign you what to do.... you need to go through the options to ensure "discoverability" is enabled. This may well be why you can't see the printer from your Android device. Source: http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/english/support/download/printer/document/user/data_mobile/CMP10UME_301.pdf (page 27 onwards)

Comment: This one doesn't have a cable it's battery powered. But I'll try pressing the power button for 5 seconds.